# Show that a function has exactly one zero

Tags: calculus, functions

I have to show that the function :

$$f(x) = 2x - \cos^2{x} + \sqrt{2}$$

Has exactly one zero in the interval $(-\infty, +\infty)$

I know that I need to find to values for $x$ which make the function once positive ($0$ here I think)  and once negative but I don’t know a value which makes it negative

Answer (score 2):

Hint:

1) what is the derivative of that function? Is $f$ a strictly monotone function?

2) what are the limits of $f$ at $\pm\infty$? Are they of different signs?

3) what do you conclude from 1 and 2?

PS finding one positive and one negative value just lets you conclude that there is at least one zero. You have also to prove there is at most one.

Comment: I think I can conclude that the derivative of the function cannot equal zero and that proves that there is no more than one point, right ? But I cannot prove that there is one root

Comment: It you prove it is positive, there is at most one zero. Then, to find a negative value: either you calculate the limits, or asl Youssef "ls $cos^2x$ bounded? How does that help me?

Answer (score 2):

**Hint**

$$f(x) = 2x - \cos^2(x) + \sqrt{2}$$
$$f'(x)=2+\sin(2x) > 0 \qquad \forall x$$

$f(x)$ is an increasing function.